# How do I view the questions marked as favourite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I've marked many questions as favourite but I'm unable to find those questions now. Then what's the point of marking them as favourite? I'm not able to find them in my profile as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at your network profile, which is linked at the top of your site profile. It should lead you [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/9974150/user404365?tab=favorites).

Alternatively, you can search for them by using `infavorites:mine` or [`infavorites:404365`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3A404365) where 404365 is your user id on the site you're searching.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I found my favourite answers